# How Do i Fix : Malformed stanza 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/librewolf.sources (type)

Tags: 14.04, debian, deepin-desktop-environment

When i try to update or install any App Using The terminal it says This  :

```
*E: Malformed stanza 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/librewolf.sources (type)
E: Type 'wget' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: Well, it seems you have some problems with your files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. You should learn how these files work, and learn how to fix them. Please start with the [Debian documentation for this](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList).

Comment: The output shows a fairly common self-inflicted problem: You did not follow the Librewolf instructions carefully enough. You inserted a command into that file instead of the correct apt source.

Comment: The error tells you that you need to edit the first line of the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/librewolf.sources` file. It even tells you that `wget` is on line 1 and commands should not be listed in a sources.list file. Although, 14.04 is many years beyond EOL and is no longer supported. [Current instructions](https://idroot.us/install-librewolf-browser-ubuntu-20-04) should overwrite the file. Additionally, Deepin desktop is not an official Ubuntu flavor and questions about Deepin are off topic here on AskUbuntu. However, questions about Deepin are on topic at https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: But using the current instructions may result in additional errors if your version of Ubuntu/Deepin is 14.04. Above all else, you should upgrade to a newer, currently supported version of Deepin or Ubuntu as the repositories for 14.04 will most likely give you a 404 error when you try and update or install software.

Comment: [Please see this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) for how to install software on, or possibly upgrade 14.04 to a newer, supported version. **Do not forget to backup your data before attempting to upgrade just in case.** But keep in mind that 14.04 was so long ago you may run into problems using this method to upgrade and it may be easier just to reinstall fresh [from a new iso image (20.04 or 22.04 recommended)](https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04/). Or download the latest version of Deepin from their website.

Comment: Actually to clarify, if you've installed Deepin desktop on an existing Ubuntu installation, the question would be on topic but questions about DeepinOS are off topic. But additionally, 14.04 is EOL and also off topic.